# Replacing specific lines containing Greater-than (>) and Less-than (<) characters in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Below is the batch file I found and it seems to work with lines that don't have Greater-than (>) and Less-than (<) symbols. The non-working lines in this example are **Replacement3** and **Replacement5**.

How to make it work with these symbols too in this particular batch file?

```
: Apache configurations.
SETLOCAL
SET "file=%mainfolder%\Applications\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf"
:: Change ServerRoot location of Apache.
SET /a Line1stToSearch=37
SET "Replacement1=ServerRoot "%mainfolderforwardslash%/Applications/Apache24""
:: Change DocumentRoot location of Apache.
SET /a Line2ndToSearch=244
SET /a Line3rdToSearch=245
SET "Replacement2=DocumentRoot "%mainfolderforwardslash%/Applications/Apache24/htdocs""
SET "Replacement3=<Directory "%mainfolderforwardslash%/Applications/Apache24/htdocs">"
:: Change ScriptAlias location of Apache.
SET /a Line4thToSearch=361
SET /a Line5thToSearch=377
SET "Replacement4=    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "%mainfolderforwardslash%/Applications/Apache24/cgi-bin/""
SET "Replacement5=<Directory "%mainfolderforwardslash%/Applications/Apache24/cgi-bin">"
:: Change the PHP module location.
SET /a Line6thToSearch=522
SET /a Line7thToSearch=525
SET "Replacement6=LoadModule php5_module "%mainfolderforwardslash%/Applications/PHP5/php5apache2_4.dll""
SET "Replacement7=PHPIniDir "%mainfolderforwardslash%/Applications/PHP5""

(FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') DO (
    SET "Line=%%b"
    IF %%a equ %Line1stToSearch% SET "Line=%Replacement1%"
    IF %%a equ %Line2ndToSearch% SET "Line=%Replacement2%"
    IF %%a equ %Line3rdToSearch% SET "Line=%Replacement3%"
    IF %%a equ %Line4thToSearch% SET "Line=%Replacement4%"
    IF %%a equ %Line5thToSearch% SET "Line=%Replacement5%"
    IF %%a equ %Line6thToSearch% SET "Line=%Replacement6%"
    IF %%a equ %Line7thToSearch% SET "Line=%Replacement7%"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    ECHO(!Line!
    ENDLOCAL
))>"%file%.new"
TYPE "%file%.new" >NUL
MOVE "%file%.new" "%file%" >NUL
ENDLOCAL
```

---

### UPDATE

Based upon @[Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64530435/14251575)'s answer, I fixed this problem by removing the existing `SETLOCAL` and `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and adding `SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` after `: Apache configurations.` (line 1) and     `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` after `(FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') DO (` (line 23).

So no code rewrite is needed so far.

Comment: modify your if conditions to use correct doublequote syntax: `IF "%%a" == "%Line1stToSearch%"`

Comment: Surely `%%a` will always only `equ` an integer, _(the line number result from `findstr`)_ @T3RR0R, so I don't see any benefit in instead using a doublequoted string comparison with `==`. In fact, I see no benefit in using `SET` at all, within the `FOR` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon my comment, here's a quick example of how I'd suggest you try it:

```
Rem Apache configurations.
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "file=%mainfolder%\Applications\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf"

Rem Change ServerRoot location of Apache.
Set "MatchedLine1=37"
Set "Replacement1=ServerRoot "%mainfolderforwardslash%/Applications/Apache24""

Rem Change DocumentRoot location of Apache.
Set "MatchedLine2=244"
Set "Replacement2=DocumentRoot "%mainfolderforwardslash%/Applications/Apache24/htdocs""

Set "MatchedLine3=245"
Set "Replacement3=<Directory "%mainfolderforwardslash%/Applications/Apache24/htdocs">"

Rem Change ScriptAlias location of Apache.
Set "MatchedLine4=361"
Set "Replacement4=    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "%mainfolderforwardslash%/Applications/Apache24/cgi-bin/""

Set "MatchedLine5=377"
Set "Replacement5=<Directory "%mainfolderforwardslash%/Applications/Apache24/cgi-bin">"

Rem Change the PHP module location.
Set "MatchedLine6=522"
Set "Replacement6=LoadModule php5_module "%mainfolderforwardslash%/Applications/PHP5/php5apache2_4.dll""

Set "MatchedLine7=525"
Set "Replacement7=PHPIniDir "%mainfolderforwardslash%/Applications/PHP5""

Copy /Y "%file%" "%file%.bak" 2> NUL 1>&2
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo :EOF

(For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=[]" %%G In (
        '%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /V /N "" 0^< "%file%.bak" 2^> NUL'
    ) Do (SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        If %%G Equ %MatchedLine1% (Echo !Replacement1!
        ) Else If %%G Equ %MatchedLine2% (Echo !Replacement2!
        ) Else If %%G Equ %MatchedLine3% (Echo !Replacement3!
        ) Else If %%G Equ %MatchedLine4% (Echo !Replacement4!
        ) Else If %%G Equ %MatchedLine5% (Echo !Replacement5!
        ) Else If %%G Equ %MatchedLine6% (Echo !Replacement6!
        ) Else If %%G Equ %MatchedLine7% (Echo !Replacement7!
        ) Else Echo(%%H
        EndLocal)) 1> "%file%"

Type "%file%"
Pause

%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /M "Would you like to now delete the original"
If Not ErrorLevel 2 Del "%file%.bak"

EndLocal
```

If you're satisfied with the output of the `Type` command, *(line `47`)*, you can optionally delete the original file, which was saved along side it, with the same name, but with an additional `.bak` extension.

Comment: Thank you. Your code is kind of rewrite. But I solved this problem based upon your code, added in my main post.

Comment: I rewrote it because your variable names were IMO badly chosen and not in an easily viewable and understandable order. In addition to those the other changes to use a copy of the file, and an optional delete are better practice than just overwriting with new, and potentially incorrect data. Also IMO using `find.exe /V /N ""` with `delims=[]` is better than using `findstr.exe /N "^"` with `delims=:` because concurrent delimiters are counted as one. It is much less likely that a source file line will start with a `]` character than a `:`, so there's less chance of one or more missed characters.

Comment: As well as that, you were using broken labels instead of correct `Rem`arks for your commentary, and `SET /a`, which is for arithmetic, when you weren't performing any arithmetic, so just `Set` was needed. Finally I used the extension and path for my external utility, _(`find`)_, because doing so removes the reliance of the easily modifiable `Path` and `PATHEXT` variables.`